# when setting up a web app in IDEA, can someone help me with Facets/Modules and Artifacts

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

using IDEA ultimate, how would I start a project and have the following layout:

```
/src/
/src/main/java/com/example/myapp
/src/main/resources
/src/main/webapp
/src/main/webapp/META-INF
/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF
/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp
/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib
/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/myapp-servlet.xml
/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

So from what I understand, once this is setup I have to now somehow wire things using Modules/Artifacts/Facets.

I have JDK and tomcat setup.

I just don't know how to wire things up, so when I hit RUN it will build, deploy the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to start creating a web project in Idea is to use either a maven project (any project with valid pom.xml and by your folder structure I guess thats what you are trying to do) Or create a project and add a web module (a module with web facet). Artifacts are like your build artifacts, your wars, jars and such things. Modules are sub projects or logical division of your main projects like common module, services, web module in a main project. Facets gives your some extra features like spring auto completion. It tells the IDE that your module is using so and so technology...

Comment: great, so I created project using pom.xml, added spring-mvc, create web.xml, xxx-servelet.xml, homecontroller, index.jsp, added tomcat. building doesn't deploy.  I didn't setup any artifacts/facets/etc. yet, so what do I do? please help thanks!

Comment: If you have not created a run/debug configuration already, start by creating one and add the artifact to the deployment tab and then start the server

Comment: Yes, you should have only one.